# Why doesn't Object.getOwnPropertyNames() list all properties and methods?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

I am trying to extract all the properties and methods from an object which happens to be a string: var `str = "Hello World!"`

If I use the command `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(str)` I get a list of properties and methods: `["0", "1", "2", "3", "length"]`. However I know there are other methods like `.toUpperCase()` which  belong to the string object but they are not listed.

**My question**: why is the method `.toUpperCase()` not listed? What can I do to list it out with many others (`.indexOf()`...)?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Display properties and methods from objects</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var str= 'Hello World!'
    var listPropertiesMethods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(str)
    console.log(listPropertiesMethods);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JonasW. I get empty array....

Comment: oh right, doesnt work with Object.keys, but with [getOwnPropertyNames](http://jsbin.com/yutiqaruka/edit?console)

Comment: @JonasW. ok but getOwnPropertyName is what I have used and doesn't return all the methods like am asking... I need to print out also the other methods like toUpperCase() for example

Comment: @JonasW. yeah sure :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cause the properties you list (`indexOf`, ...) are not part of the string object itself, but are rather part of its prototype:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
 Object.getPrototypeOf("str")
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have just look at the proto-type of your object and you get what you want:

```
console.log(str.__proto__);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)` method returns only the properties of the obj (like length). You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` to get a more complete list of methods/properties.

Ex.:

Object.getOwnPropertyNames("Test")

```
(5) ["0", "1", "2", "3", "length"]
```

Object.getPrototypeOf("Test")

```
String {"", formatUnicorn: ƒ, truncate: ƒ, splitOnLast: ƒ, contains: ƒ, length: 0, …}
```